# Prove that if $|f(x)| \leq x^2$, then the function is continuous and differentiable at $x=0$.

Tags: continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $|f(x)| \leq x^2$ .
Prove whether or not the function is continuous and differentiable at $x=0$.

Please tell me where am i wrong 
i have used the sandwich theorem :

$-x^2 \leq f(x) \leq x^2$,
so $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0} x^2 = \lim_{x \to 0}(-x^2) = 0 $

also , $f(0)=0$

hence the function is continuous and differentiable

Comment: this proves continuity not differentiability.

Answer (score 8):

You've proved continuity and that $f(0) = 0$. To prove differentiability, you need to prove that $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x-0}$$ exists. However, this simplifies to proving $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}$$ exists. And by the given condition, we see $$\left | \frac{f(x)}{x} \right| \le \lvert x \rvert .$$ Thus $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x} = 0$$ which shows that $f$ is differentiable at $0$ with $f'(0)=0$.

Comment: I think you meant $|f(x)/x|\le|x|$.  Also, your first limit should be $x\to0$ not $x\to\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for the note! Yes you are correct on both accounts.

Comment: but I think we should assume that $x \neq 0$ ..... correct?