# If $-x^2 \leq f(x) \leq x^2$ for all $x \in R$, prove that f is differentiable.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

If $-x^2 \leq f(x) \leq x^2$ for all $x \in R$ prove that f is differentiable.

I have found this link here for differentiability at 0, but what about the rest of the proof? Any ideas will be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Here is the link:

[Prove that if $|f(x)| \leq x^2$, then the function is continuous and differentiable at $x=0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1722276/prove-that-if-fx-leq-x2-then-the-function-is-continuous-and-differentia)

Comment: It's not true outside of 0. Make a piecewise linear function which is y=0 around 0.

Comment: I apologize for that comment about being a duplicate. I had two windows open at once and pasted it into the wrong window.

Comment: Question refers to a link, but there is no link provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With just the given condition that $-x^2 \le f(x) \le x^2$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, it is even possible that $f$ is discontinuous everywhere except $x = 0$, and thus, not differentiable anywhere except $x = 0$. Consider the function $$f(x) = \begin{cases}x^2 & \text{if} \ x \in \mathbb{Q} \\ 0 & \text{if} \ x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}\end{cases}.$$

Comment: okay great..... do I have to assume that $x \neq 0$ to continue the proof as that given in the link above?

Comment: I am wondering from where we get the line before last in the link mentioned above?

Answer (score 4):

It is only true at $x=0$

You can make a zig zag between $x^2$ and $-x^2$ Which is not differentiable.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't even have to be continuous.

Consider $$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & x\lt 2 \\
1, & x\ge 2
\end{cases}$$